What do the stamps on this English travel document mean?
It's an A3 sheet, on the recto is a Marriage License, perfectly obvious. But on the verso there are some rubber stamp marks from various railroad companies with filled in dates, a number, and signed by a registrar or a secretary. Do these registrations mark a trip, or are they just some reservation for a trip that did not necessarily happen? Or perhaps just for sending luggage in advance?
Link to Image

Below is the list which suggests a trip around the world


Grand Trunk Railway Company of Canada
The Buenos Ayres Great Southern Railway Company, Argentina
The Assam Railways & Trading Company, India (German only)
The Hull Barnsley & West Riding Junction Railway and Dock Company, UK


FFR, its best to actually upload the image to the site, rather than just link to it. This allows people to see your explanatory text for the question along with the image without switching tabs or windows. I've done it here for you.

In 1904, it seems very unlikely that you could physically be registered in Buenos Aires on November 28th and in Canada 2 days later though.

If I correctly read the cursive writing, we have 1. ? 2. Burrows 3. Bowden 4. Freidrich. Why on earth would different names be used on the same sheet?

@OldPadawan 'Why on earth would different names be used on the same sheet?' Four different companies, four different signatures of the corresponding Registrars/Secrateries is not strange at all.

@MarkJohnson: thought it was the client name, not the clerck :)

Adding an image of the front sheet may be more useful for this question. An A3 sheet was, in many countries, not uncommon for passports untill the early 1920's.

@MarkJohnson - the A series of paper sizes was not even developed until 1921, in Germany as DIN Norm 476 so I am doubtful about 'A3 passports' prior to (or after) that.

@MichaelHarvey And yet such Passports with a large sheet (instead of a booklet) did exist.

I believe this is not to do with travel at all, but with shares in the companies named. My guess is that the wife held stock in each of those companies, and after changing her surname on marriage was obliged to inform the companies so that they could update their records. (Fallback guess: if the marriage was in 1882 or earlier, and this is just very late paperwork, then something else is going on, for which see below.) The marriage document was evidence for that, and would have been stamped by each company registrar as part of the process.
Some of the signatures come with the title "registrar", denoting a company officer responsible for keeping track of shareholders. Sometimes there is a "registrar of transfers" or other title; generically, this might be done by the company secretary in a smaller operation. British companies legislation from the 19th century (and all these companies were headquartered in the British Empire) imposed requirements of this kind as a condition of operating as a company.
When somebody sold shares, they were meant to do so by "deed of transfer" which would be delivered to the appropriate officer of the company. Until that deed was registered, the original shareholder was still on the hook if there were a call notice, and the intended new beneficiary would not receive any dividends. By legislation (the Companies Clauses Consolidation Act 1845, s.15), the deed of transfer would also receive an "endorsement" by the registrar to indicate that it had been recorded in the company's records.
Naturally, shares might also be transferred due to the death of the original shareholder, in which case there is no deed. But there was a similar process (same Act, s.18) for registering a declaration describing what had happened, plus the associated probate documents. Prior to the Married Women's Property Acts of 1881 (Scotland) and 1882 (England), a woman's stock would pass to her husband upon marriage, and there was also a process for registering that event, attested by the marriage certificate or similar document. If the marriage in question took place prior to the commencement date of those acts, then it was still possible for a consequent transfer to be registered.
However, on the assumption that the marriage was in 1904, this is probably a simpler clerical matter of updating the company register to refer to the woman's married name. I think what has happened in this case is that the woman named in the marriage document held shares in several railway companies. From late November 1904 through early January 1905, she and/or her husband filed the necessary paperwork with each company registrar in turn, including the marriage document. Each time, the registrar endorsed that document with a stamp as part of the recording process, as they would have done with a deed of transfer or anything else. The dates and identifying numbers would refer to entries in the company's registers.
I found a guidebook from 1893 which contains a standard form for filing change-of-name paperwork with the registrar. It also describes briefly that

On the marriage of a female proprietor the registrar should require a copy of the certificate of marriage, and a statutory declaration declaring the identity of the wife with the holder of the property, before registering the property in her married name.

This text also indicates the obsolesence of the transfer-on-marriage provisions, except for a marriage solemnized prior to the date I mentioned.

Thank You. You are most probably right: among the stamps 7 are from railway companies but there is one that is from "The Australian Estates & Mortgage company". I will take one more look at the document before acknowledging your post as the answer.

Good catch for the shares! What still puzzle me is how close the days on the stamps are. In 1904/05, it takes days/weeks/months for letters to be delivered. If you send the marriage document to one company in one country, it'll take more than 2 days to come back or be sent to another place. Unless said companies have local offices in the same town, how can we explain the dates/stamps collected on the same document?

@OldPadawan Wikpiedia: "The Buenos Aires Great Southern Railway (BAGS) (Spanish: Ferrocarril del Sud) was one of the Big Four broad gauge, ... British-owned companies that built and operated railway networks in Argentina." [emph. mine].  They were probably all headquartered in London. Two others were in British colonies and one in the UK.

@ChrisH: thanks! you comment should probably be added as clarification/help in the answer IMHO though...

@OldPadawan perhaps the answer's "(and all these companies were headquartered in the British Empire) " could be modified, but it's also possible that some did indeed have HQs overseas but a business office of some sort in London; the research needed to be sure is beyond me

Possibly someone could have popped round in person rather than waiting for the post. It would not be too hard to identify the contemporary office locations, but we'd also need the other side of the document to help with guesses about logistics - it would show where the people lived and where they were (recently) wed. But that all seems a bit marginal to the main question.
